# “Hide” YouTube's embedded video spinning circle

Tags: css, iframe, youtube

I'm using an YouTube video as background. The div also has an image as background for mobile devices, when the video doesn't play.

What happens is on page load it briefly displays the image, then goes to black with spinning circle dots, then the video starts.

Is there a way to skip/hide the black screen with the spinning circle?

Answer (score 0):

YouTube insists on iframes, I believe it is against their TOS to access videos any other way. If they didn't use iframes you could apply the following css to elements that appear in your DOM.

```
.ytp-spinner { display:none;}
.player-api {background-color: transparent;}
.player-unavailable {background-color: transparent;}
.html5-video-player {background-color: transparent;}
.ytp-gradient-top {background-image: none;}
.typ-gradient-bottom {background-image: none;}
```

These are the bits that would likely hide the offending parts of the video (the pre-load).

You're going to have to try something else, if you own the video, I would suggest attempting something like the following.

1. Edit the video so the first ~5-10 seconds are a still image frame.
2. Use javascript to hide the entire youtube iframe while it loads.
3. You could try to match the image so the transition is fairly seamless.

The variable you can't control is the users load speed so you might have to do a bit of testing to get the timing to work in most instances. Good luck -R

Comment: I think there are many layers with a black background: .player-api .player-unavailable .html5-video-player when disabled in webtools get rid of the black screen. it's a start

Comment: It looks like there could be 10 or more layers you need to set background: transparent or opacity:0 or display:none. I will see if I can list some more in the answer.